vuelidate - validating dynamically added/removed fields does not behave as expected
I've been working on a Vue 3 application that utilizes Vuelidate for form validation. The form includes dynamic fields, specifically the questions array, where users can add or remove fields as needed. Each field within the questions array has its own validation rules, such as being required.
The issue I'm facing is related to the validation state of the fields when a field is removed from the questions array. Here's a detailed description of the problem:

Initial State:

Let's say I have three fields in the questions array.
I interact with fields 2 and 3, triggering their validation. If they don't meet the validation criteria, Vuelidate correctly marks them as invalid.


Removing a Field:

I decide to remove field 2 from the questions array.
Before removing the field, I call jobAdFormValidation.value.questions[questionIndex].$reset() to clear the validation state of the field being removed. This ensures that the validation state associated with the removed field is properly reset.


Shifting of Fields:

After removing field 2, field 3 shifts up and takes the position of field 2.
However, Vuelidate does not automatically update the validation state based on the new positions of the fields.


Validation State Issue:

The validation state that was previously associated with field 3 remains incorrectly attached to the original field 3 position, even though field 3 has now shifted up to become the new field 2.
As a result, the newly shifted field (now at position 2) loses its validation error state, even though it should retain the validation error from its previous position.


Adding a New Field:

If I then decide to add a new field at position 3 (where the deleted field used to be), Vuelidate incorrectly applies the validation error state from the previously removed field to this newly added field.
This means that the new field at position 3 starts with an invalid state, even though it hasn't been interacted with or validated yet.



The core problem lies in how Vuelidate handles the validation state when fields are dynamically removed and the remaining fields shift positions. The validation state doesn't correctly follow the fields as they move to new positions, leading to incorrect validation errors being applied to the wrong fields.
I've tried various approaches to resolve this issue, such as resetting the validation state of the removed field, revalidating the entire questions array, and even attempting to manually update the validation state. However, none of these solutions have completely addressed the problem of the validation state being lost or incorrectly applied when fields are removed and shifted.
This is how I define my rules in my composable:
export function useJobAdValidation() {
const { vuelidateInstance, useVuelidate } = useVuelidateValidation();
const jobStore = useJobStore();

const questionRules = computed(() =>
    jobStore.jobAd.questions.map(() => ({
        id: { required, numeric },
        question: { required },
        idealAnswer: { required }
    }))
);

const rules = computed(() => ({
    title: { required, text },
    description: { required, text },
    roleName: { required, text },
    department: { text },
    salary: {
        currency: { required, text },
        min: { required, numeric },
        max: { required, numeric },
    },
    officeLocation: { required, text },
    employmentTypeCode: { required, text },
    candidateRequirements: jobStore.jobAd.candidateRequirements.map(() => ({
        id: { required, numeric },
        requirement: { required, text },
    })),
    candidateResponsibilities: jobStore.jobAd.candidateResponsibilities.map(() => ({
        id: { required, numeric },
        responsibility: { required, text},
    })),
    questions: questionRules.value,
    adGoLiveDate: { required, text },
    jobStartDate: { required, text },
    expiresAt: { required, text },
}));

const jobAdFormValidation = vuelidateInstance(rules, jobStore.jobAd);

return {
    jobAdFormValidation,
};
}

I am not entirely sure what else I can do. All I want is to be able to add fields dynamically and have them validated. That is all, however vuelidate seems to just not like it.
This is is how I trigger validation (there is no issue with that part):
<Input
    :id="`question-${index}`"
    :label="`Question ${index + 1}`"
    v-model="question.question"
    @blur="jobAdFormValidation?.questions[index]?.question.$touch"
    :error-message="errors(index, 'question')"
    :variant="errors(index, 'question') ? 'error' : 'default'"
    placeholder="What's the meaning of life?"
/>

This is what happens when I remove the field (there's an icon above the input):
const handleQuestionDelete = () => {
    const questionIndex = jobStore.findLocalQuestionIndex(deleteQuestionId.value);
    jobAdFormValidation.value.questions[questionIndex].$reset();
    jobStore.deleteLocalQuestionById(deleteQuestionId.value);
    questionRefs.value.splice(questionIndex, 1);
    deleteQuestionDialogState.value = false;
};

So by doing these basic action I can remove the validation state before I delete the field so that part is ok. However if I delete the field 2 and field 3 has validation error state it does lose that state when it becomes field number 2. When I re-add field it automatically get the validation error that must linger.
What I would expect to see is that when field 3 has an error and I delete the field number 2, the field number 3 keeps the error. Hence the computed property around my rules.
HOW TO REPRODUCE

Create Pinia store instance with:

import {defineStore} from "pinia";

const JobsStore = {
    state: () => {
        return {
            jobAd: {questions: [{id: 1, question: '', idealAnswer: ''}] as { id: number, question: string; idealAnswer: string }[],}
        }
    },   
}
const jobStore = defineStore('JobStore', JobStore)


Push to store so you have 3 objects

jobStore.jobAd.questions.push({id:'', question:'', idealAnswer:''});

Please note: in actual app there is no loop that adds questions or anything of that nature. There is a simple button that in essence does what the above code shows, the only extra thing that happens is ID calculation, but this is just for data purposes.

Create the vuelidate instance based on the rules from the composable attached above. For our example we just need to use questions rules. The vuelidateInstance is just from my core custom cpomposable that essentailly creates the vuelidate instance with native vuelidate function useVuelidate(rules, dataFields);

When you use $touch() on previously pushed object 2 and 3 in questions jobAdFormValidation?.questions[index]?.question.$touch and remove middle question the last 3rd (now second after removal) element will lose it's valiation. If we re-add the field so push another object it will be automaticaly bound to lingering validation from vuelidate.


So if you were to execute this while having 3 questions added:
jobAdFormValidation?.questions[1]?.question.$touch

jobAdFormValidation?.questions[2]?.question.$touch

This is the function I use to extract the errors:
const errors = (index: number, property: string) => {
    return jobAdFormValidation.value?.questions?.[index]?.$errors
        ?.find(e => e.$propertyPath === `questions.${index}.${property}`)
        ?.$message || null;
};

The above is purely so I can grab the correct property from the object.
